# How does folks currently handle giving Emacs permissions to the ~/Downloads directory on osx Monterey 12.3

Tags: emacs

Currently I get this error

```
 (file-error \"File cannot be opened\" \"Operation not permitted\" \"/Users/foo/Downloads\")")
```

In other answers I've seen we give ruby all the permissions as described here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371888/restore-access-to-file-system-for-emacs-on-macos-catalina/371945#371945

but is this still the case? Is there an alternative? I am on Emacs 27.2

Comment: Which Emacs exactly are you asking about? There are three moderately popular GNU Emacs versions for MacOS (Emacs for MacOS, Homebrew, and Aquamacs). How did you install it?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's hard to control the app permissions for a specific directory on macOS (you can't add it in settings, and it only prompts on first access or something I'm not sure about), I recommend enabling Full Disk Access permissions for Emacs.

Another option to try is to reset the app Privacy and then confirm it the next time you are prompted (to access files in the Downloads folder).

```sh
# codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Emacs.app
sudo tccutil reset All org.gnu.Emacs
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `emacsformacos`.
That is using a wrapper in ruby to decide which binary to run.

As nobody wants to give ruby full control I compiled it myself for some time.

With 28.1 I switched to

```
port install emacs-mac-app
```